# How to deploy next.js application to AWS, What is the entry file for the server?

Tags: next.js, web-deployment, awsdeploy

Am using nextjs project. From the below image, you can find my folder structure. In my local machine, I can complete the npm run build and npm run start. the build creation and page display are done successfully. when am trying to host the project in the AWS webserver I can't display my page. build creation was successful. but the page URL returns 502, or 403 errors.

[image: project structure]

**Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "yadara-frontend-next",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint",
    "export" : "next export"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "compression-webpack-plugin": "^9.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^10.2.4",
    "cra-template-pwa": "1.0.3",
    "dotenv-webpack": "^7.1.0",
    "env-cmd": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "8.29.0",
    "eslint-config-next": "13.0.6",
    "form-data": "^4.0.0",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "gzipper": "6.0.0",
    "hookrouter": "^1.2.5",
    "html-react-parser": "^1.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.11.6",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "next": "13.0.6",
    "pdf-merger-js": "^4.1.0",
    "qs": "^6.10.1",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.2",
    "react-content-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.6.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-geolocated": "^3.2.0",
    "react-google-login": "^5.2.2",
    "react-input-range": "^1.3.0",
    "react-lazyload": "^3.2.0",
    "react-payment-inputs": "^1.1.8",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.4",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-scroll": "^1.8.4",
    "react-select": "^4.3.1",
    "react-slick": "^0.28.1",
    "redux": "^4.1.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "sharethis-reactjs": "^1.6.0",
    "slick-carousel": "^1.8.1",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.1",
    "universal-cookie": "^4.0.4",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.9"
  }
}
```

should I have to update any changes on package.json data? what is the entry point for the AWS server? am using server-side rendering on the _app.js page, so am not having any index.html files in the build.

```
                                       **Thanks for your effort**
```

Comment: Are you talking about EC2? Wouldn't Vercel make more sense?

Comment: Yeah, mention about EC2-instance using ubuntu 8.0. @pguardiario

Comment: There's a lot of ways to configure it, virtual host with nginx maybe? Consider switching to Vercel though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no root path for this in webconfig file. You should configure it as reverse proxy in webconfig file as below,

```
    location / {
            proxy_pass             http://127.0.0.1:3000;
            proxy_read_timeout     60;
            proxy_connect_timeout  60;
            proxy_redirect         off;

            # Allow the use of websockets
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
```

before start the pm2 service using below command

$ pm2 --name dev-name start npm -- start

Then configure the env file as per your requirement